# How to delete all data in CoreData?

Tags: iphone, core-data

Is there a quick way to clear all data of my CoreData without calling deleteObject for each entity in the model?

Answer (score 2):

Delete the persistent store on disk (after calling `-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator removePersistentStore:error:]` for any persistent store coordinator that refers to the store). You probably also want to reset any `NSManagedObjectContext` instances that may have managed object instances from that store before removing and deleting the store on disk.

Answer (score 0):

You can release all your `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` and all you `NSManagedObjectContest`'s then delete the file in the FS and recreate it.